# Reading a text file into Java by using a "double" method

Tags: java, file, java-8

I have a simple text file with the following content:

```
4 5 2 7
```

I would like Java to read this file and create an array with it. However, I want my method that I use to keep its "double" properties. I'm having a hard time getting my array command to figure it out though:

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets; 
import java.nio.file.*; 
import java.io.*; 

public class ReadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        gns(Arr);
    }
    public static double gns(String TxtFile) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\me\\files\\inputfiles");
        int numLines = (int)Files.lines(path).count();
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("TxtFile.txt"));
        double Arr = new ArrayList<String>();
        return Arr;
        }
}
```

It keeps giving me an array due to the type of the array.

Comment: What is the parameter `String TxtFile`, `C:\\Users\\me\\files\\inputfiles` and `TxtFile.txt`?

Comment: This code doesn't compile as is. Please try and post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what is this line `double Arr = new ArrayList<String>();` doing in your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick :

```
double[] arr = Files.lines(Paths.get(PATH))
                    .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(" ")))
                    .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
                    .toArray();
```

Here we read the file line by line and then split it using `" "`, parse each number and covert it to an array of `double`. You can then return `arr[]` from your method             `gns(String TxtFile)`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Scanner#nextDouble

Give a try to the following one, full example below:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class NextDouble {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<Double>();
    while (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
      doubles.add(sc.nextDouble());
    }

    System.out.println(doubles); // => [1.0, 3.0, 8.0, 6.0, 5.0]

  }
}
```

`input.txt` contains the following line:

```
1 3 8 6 5
```

You can find more about scanner in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble())

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set `Arr` which is of type `double` to an `ArrayList` of type `String`, this is not possible since the types `double` and `ArrayList` are different.

If you wanted an arraylist of doubles use

```
ArrayList<Double> d = new ArrayList<>();
```